# How to get ApplicationDbContext out of the Owin pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-identity-2

This has to be simple, but I'm going bug-eyed trying to find the answer.  How does a controller action get a reference to the per-request ApplicationDbContext that was stashed in the Owin pipeline?

EDIT: Ok, I think I'm getting closer... or maybe not...  All of my Googling seems to lead to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx), which sez to use:

```
var dbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

where context is apparently an instance of `Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext`.  So I tried:

```
var db = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

But the `Get<T>` method requires a `string key` parameter. :(

Answer (score 32, accepted):

And the answer (apparently) is...  **You need to add this using statement to get it to work:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

so a complete example would look like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        DoSomething(context); // Use the context object; do not dispose it!

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: God finally! Thank you for mentioning the import, for some reason it wasn't suggested and I couldnt figure out why my code didnt compile.

Comment: you are what they call a "savior" .... i had everything right just not the right using statement, yet there was still a method call with the same name so no compile errors about the namespace